# How to read the contents of a zipped URL using php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am using php for one of my projects. I have a URl which has the set of XML of a specific site. The URL is in the format www.sitefeed.com/somekey&&gZipCompress=yes. I want to read the contents of this file with out downloading it into my server.

I tried compress.zlib: in front of the URL but it returned an empty array.

Thanks

Comment: use file_get_contents or else curl

Comment: How can you read the contents of the (zip)file without downloading it?

Comment: I think he means, without storing it on its hard drive

Comment: Yes i dont want it to get stored. But would like to get the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your php variable "allow_url_fopen" on, you can use:

```
$lrc = gzopen($the_link, "r");
$text ="";
while(!gzeof($lrc)){
    $text .= gzread($lrc, 1024);
}
gzclose($lrc);
```

If not, you can use file_get_contents, or even curl .

Comment: Thanks a lot timmalos:) Your code did the trick:) Have accepted your answer!

Comment: Apart from this i also wanted to convert the xml to a array format. I did that with http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array. Thanks a lot to all who helped me:):) U saved my life:):)